# Rails 4 Nested Form not Passing Nested Attributes in Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, strong-parameters

When I submit the form it is passing `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blah", "client"=>{"first_name"=>"jack", "last_name"=>"kool","complaints"=>{"symptom"=>"burnt"}` in the params and I am getting `Unpermitted Parameters: complaints` Since complaints is nested in Client, it should be passing `complaints_attributes`, like I have it set up in the strong params, and I can't figure out why it isn't.

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

 def new
  @client = Client.new
 end

 def edit
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)

  if @client.save
   redirect_to @client
  else
   render 'new'
  end  
end

def update
 @client = Client.find(params[:id])

 if @client.update(client_params)
  redirect_to @client
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

private

 def client_params
   params.require(:client).permit(:first_name, :last_name, complaints_attributes: [ :symptom, :id ])
 end
end
```

Client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :complaints
 has_one :personal_disease_history
 has_one :family_disease_history
 has_many :surgeries
 has_many :hospitalizations
 has_many :medications
 has_many :allergies

 validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints
end
```

Complaint model:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :client
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for :client, url: clients_path, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |f| %>
 <div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title">Health History Form</h3>
  </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-blocks"><legend>Name</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :first_name, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name"  %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :last_name, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last Name"  %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-blocks"><legend>Complaints</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :complaints do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :symptom, class: "sr-only" %>
        <%= builder.text_field :symptom, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Symptom"  %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Form", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the controller, try building your Client model with `.build` instead of calling `.new` on it.  This should build the associated Complaint onto Client.

Comment: if that doesn't work, a hacky, temporary solution would be to say Complaint.create(params["complaints"]) inside your Clients controller create action.

Comment: @harishsr Adding `.build` in place of `.new` yields a no method error

Comment: @toddmetheny your suggestion saves a record to the complaints db table, but 'symptom' is null and I am still seeing 'Unpermitted parameter: complaints'. Definitely progress but I need the data to persist.

Comment: do you have reference to client on your complaint table?

Comment: yes, client_id @toddmetheny

Comment: have couple other ideas: but (1) you have complaint_attributes in the permitted params but you coiuld change that to complaint bc that's what's coming through in the params.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting? I suspect you'll have to type `fields_for :complaint do |builder|` in your view instead of pluralizing complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside client controller create action, try saying this inside the if @client.save:

```
Complaint.create(symptom: params[
"client"]["complaints"]["symptom"], client_id: @client.id)
```

the unpermitted parameter is related to the nested attribute problem but this should get the actual record saving. If that doesn't do it, please post the stack trace surrounding the commit.

have couple other ideas: but (1) you have complaint_attributes in the permitted params but you could change that to complaint bc that's what's coming through in the params.

Comment: This actually works, but as you said it seems hacky. Does this method also open security vulnerabilities since the params aren't in the private `client_params` method? Any ideas for making it less hacky? Regardless, thanks for your help.

Comment: @rymcmahon please accept answer if it works :) To make it less hacky you could try to get it working as nested attributes as you have been. Your form_for probably needs to be passed both objects. Hard to explain but something like form_for [:client, :complaint] instead of just form_for :client.

Comment: I found a less hacky solution. I changed `<%= form_for :client, url: clients_path, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |f| %>` to  `<%= form_for (@client), html: { class: "form-inline" } do |f| %>` and added `@client.complaints.build` to the new action in client. Thanks for the lead.